# Pandas mismatched column names join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas pivot_table of some time-series health data like so:

[image: pivot_table]

I want to get the quotient of these two metrics for each hospital for each body type for each time, like so:

[image: my_metric]

How can I achieve this in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by moving `bodytype` from `columns` to `index` by creating a different pivot_table, and then simply dividing.

`pivot_df["my_metric"] = pivot_df["heart_rate"] / pivot_df["blood_pressure"]`

Comment: You didn't really answer your own question.  You presented a different format because it was easier for you to do.  First of all, you can finish the job by `pivot_df.unstack('bodytype')`.  Secondly, I'd say it's bad form to ask a question without providing the data needed to generate the pivot table and then offer a solution that depends on the data you didn't provide.  How does that help others?

Answer (score 2):

A better solution can be had if you provided a sample of data pre-pivot.

```
hr = df.heart_rate
bp = df.blood_pressure

keys = ['heart_rate', 'blood_pressure', 'my_metric']
pd.concat([hr, bp, hr / bp], axis=1, keys=keys)
```

---

**Example**

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
        ['t%s'%i for i in range(1, 6)],
        ['h1', 'h2']
    ], names=['Time', 'Hospital'])
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
        ['heart_rate', 'blood_pressure'],
        ['Type1', 'Type2']
    ], names=['metric', 'bodytype'])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 4)),
    idx, col
)

df

metric        heart_rate       blood_pressure      
bodytype           Type1 Type2          Type1 Type2
Time Hospital                                      
t1   h1                6     3              8     3
     h2                3     4              2     9
t2   h1                5     7              7     0
     h2                9     4              9     4
t3   h1                8     8              7     9
     h2                5     5              3     5
t4   h1                0     1              5     1
     h2                4     9              5     9
t5   h1                0     0              1     5
     h2                2     0              5     0
```

---

```
hr = df.heart_rate
bp = df.blood_pressure

keys = ['heart_rate', 'blood_pressure', 'my_metric']
pd.concat([hr, bp, hr / bp], axis=1, keys=keys)

              heart_rate       blood_pressure       my_metric          
bodytype           Type1 Type2          Type1 Type2     Type1     Type2
Time Hospital                                                          
t1   h1                6     3              8     3  0.750000  1.000000
     h2                3     4              2     9  1.500000  0.444444
t2   h1                5     7              7     0  0.714286       inf
     h2                9     4              9     4  1.000000  1.000000
t3   h1                8     8              7     9  1.142857  0.888889
     h2                5     5              3     5  1.666667  1.000000
t4   h1                0     1              5     1  0.000000  1.000000
     h2                4     9              5     9  0.800000  1.000000
t5   h1                0     0              1     5  0.000000  0.000000
     h2                2     0              5     0  0.400000       NaN
```